# How can I commit both my frontend and backend folders to github as one folder?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, repository

I have two folders in my setup, an express backend and a react frontend which I created with `npx create-react-app`. I want to push both to the same repository in the same branch but the problem is when I downloaded my react app and check my source control, it split up for some reason. I did `git init` in the root directory which contained both these folders but it still split them up in the source control:

[image]

I'm not sure how to push them to the same repository, some advice or things I should do at the start would be helpful. I'm able to download my backend and create a new frontend since I haven't really done much with my frontend so if a solution which requires me to do something from the get-go of installing react arises, I can do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your frontend and backend folders each have their own `.git` folders within. Which would make each of them a git repository as that's where all source control data is kept.

If you are fine with wiping out their history (not your changes/files), then delete the two `.git` folders and try again from the root directory containing both folders.

Comment: What do i do once I delete each file?

Comment: @Soccerball123 you don't delete a file you delete any `.git` folder not in the workspace root folder, set a correct remote for the `.git` in the workspace root folder and that not being any of the previous github projects

Comment: @Soccerball123 once you've deleted them, you should be good to go. You've effectively reverted the folders from being git repositories. So as rioV8 says, set a remote for the root git repo and commit/push/whatever.

Comment: But when I created the react app, I didn't see any `.git` folder in either workspace (backend or frontend). Then I went and did `git init` at the root of the directory which holds both folders and did `git remote add ...` and added my repo url. But I'm still seeing it getting branched into two different things in the source control, there's not `.git` folder in either directory and not even at the root when I clicked on the folder. Did I do something wrong, could I know what specific commands to execute since I feel like that might be the reason why I can't get it to work.

Comment: Oh wait nevermind, I had to enable hidden folders. I got it to work now thank you. I'm able to push both folders and changes to github now but I still see the source control changes for the frontend still, not sure how to get rid of that so if you do know, that would be helpful but not really important

Comment: damnit, I knew this answer but completely forgot when trying to push my back-end. Thanks for saving me a headache!